# Using '*' in docker exec command

Tags: linux, windows, docker, containers, system

I am trying to run specific command inside running docker container.

```
 Docker exec -t containername1 ls /tmp/sth/*
```

in return I receive

```
 ls: cannot access '/tmp/sth/*': No such file or directory
```

In fact when I execute command while inside container everything works. Container is using Debian and local machine is using Windows. I was trying to find it, but could not.

Comment: This is normal/expected behavior. In the UNIX world, globs are expanded *by your shell* before that shell starts a program; thus, when `ls` is invoked, it expects to already be passed a list of files in `/tmp/sth`, not a wildcard. In this case, the glob is only valid inside the container, so the shell *outside* the container can't see the results to expand it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want a shell *inside the container* to expand your glob, you need to... well... actually run a shell inside the container. The one outside the container can't see files inside the container (of course), so it passes `ls` the literal pattern, not a list of files in the directory as you intend.

Thus:

```
docker exec -t t1 sh -c "ls /tmp/sth/*"
```

...note that I'd usually use single-quotes for the command, but since your host is Windows, using double quotes since they're more likely to work from `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Code which you'have provided totally worked and you covered also question "why?" what is always nice to have ;)