# docker copy all files in directory with given extention

Tags: linux, docker, server, copy

I can copy one file from a docker container to the server with

```
docker cp docker_session_name:/root/mydir/ .
```

I would like know to copy only files from mydir with a given extension, say, pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with `docker cp command`

To do this you can mount the directory inside the docker and then you can run the regular cp command with regex to copy it to another directory.

Mount:

```
docker run -d --name containerName -v myvol2:/app imageName:tag
```

Inside Container:

```
cp app/*.pdf /destination
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you cant just run like in Linux (see [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806102/copy-folder-with-wildcard-from-docker-container-to-host))

**Not like this:**

```
docker cp docker_session_name:/root/mydir/*.pdf .
```

### simple answer

use this script:

```
path="/root/mydir"
for file in $(docker exec docker_session_name sh -c "ls ${path}/*.pdf"); do
        docker cp docker_session_name:${file} .
done
```

credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742892/using-in-docker-exec-command) thread

### cumbersome answer with easier use (no script)

you could however mount a bind mount between the host and the wanted path like so in the `docker run` command:

```
docker run -v /host/path/:/root/mydir/ my-image
```

then run cp with wildcard `*.pdf` from the host path of `/host/path/` used in the `docker run` command

Comment: Since the globbing should happen inside docker, shouldn't you enclose the `*` into quotes?

Comment: what is 4c40aedcdaa6

Comment: sorry it my container id, I'll edit the answer

Comment: could you write the full cp with wildcard *.pdf from the host path of /host/path/ used in the docker run command

Comment: "use this script" is this a python script

Comment: if you'd use the `docker run` command then you can use a normal linux cp command with wildcards

Comment: the script is a bash script though is doesn't allow wildcards as well

Comment: so simple answer with no wild cards is not selecting the .pdf files at all ...

Comment: revised solution with that option

Comment: @NoamYizraeli: The way you wrote, the expression `*.pdf` will be parameter expanded inside the current process, i.e. the one **invoking** the `docker` command. If I understood the OP correctly, he wants the expansion happen in the files inside the docker.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes that is what he wanted but according to the current state of things with the `docker cp` command and other similar posts referenced in the answer - such a thing isn't possible. So in the lack of the exact solution, I proposed a different one that will work and won't cause too much of a hassle

Comment: what is my-image in `docker run -v /host/path/:/root/mydir/ my-image` and can you explicit (illustrate with a line of code) `then run cp with wildcard *.pdf from the host path of /host/path/ used in the docker run command`

Comment: `my-image` is the image you used for the container that you want to copy from. Regarding the copying bit you can use a command like this one while in the host os (not in the container) `cp /host/path/".pdf /root/dir-for-pdfs/`